# How to use "OR LIKE" within "AND" condition Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm facing some problems in fetching records. The table structures are as follows :

```
main_categories
------------------
id      name
1       NNN
2       PPP

categories
-----------------------------------
id      name    main_category_id
-----------------------------------
1       abc         1
2       xyz         2
3       lmn         1

services
------------------
id  categories
------------------
1   a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:2:"3";}
2   a:1:{i:0;s:3:"2";}
3   a:1:{i:0;s:3:"3";}
4   a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:3:"3";}
```

Categories stored in the services are in serialized form.

In a form I have dropdowns according to the main category and in each dropdown there are sub categories.

The post data are in this format :

array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => 1,
        [1] => 3,
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [0] => 2
    )
)

The process id like this : 5 dropdowns as per main category and the options are their sub categories and I want to put 'OR' condition in between the sub categories or same main category and 'AND' condition with the other set of 'OR' conditions of other Main Category.

In raw SQL I do this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE (`categories` LIKE '%"1"%' OR `categories` LIKE '%"3"%') AND (`categories` LIKE '%"2"%')
```

In Laravel I tried the following :

```
$categories = [1,3];

\DB::table ('services')
->where(function($q) use ($categories) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $q->where('services.categories', 'like', '%"'.DB::raw($category).'"%');
    }
})
```

But this is not working. How this could be properly done in Laravel.

Comment: u can use `orwhere` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses

Comment: @WalksAway I tried this but it is not working. It gets all the services having categories as 1 or 3 but I want only those services that have 1,3 both as categories

Comment: @WalksAway I've updated my question. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

The code is a bit ugly, but probably will work for your case. So, try this:

```
$categories = [1,3];

\DB::table ('services')
->where(function($q) use ($categories) {
    foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
        if ($key == 0) {
            $q->where('services.categories', 'like', '%"'.DB::raw($category).'"%');
        } else {
            $q->orWhere('services.categories', 'like', '%"'.DB::raw($category).'"%');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But now again my client has changed his mind updated the requirements. I've updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are lookig for `orWhere()`:

```php
orWhere('name', 'like', 'John')
```

Comment: Thank you Yada for your response. But it it is not working. It gets all the services having categories as 1 or 3 but I want only those services that have 1,3 both as categories

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had same issue while trying to search the data based on given array of value. So By looping `orWhere` inside the wrapped `where` has generated the query that I was looking for

```
$array = [
        [1, 3],
        [2],
        [7,10],
        [5, 9, 13],
        [8],
    ];

    DB::table('services')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($array) {
            foreach ($array as $eachArray) {
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($eachArray) {
                    foreach ($eachArray as $eachElement) {
                        $query->orWhere('categories', 'LIKE', $eachElement);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        ->dd();
```

So this is the output of the Above Query Builder.

```
select * from `services` where ((`categories` LIKE ? or `categories` LIKE ?) and (`categories` LIKE ?) and (`categories` LIKE ? or `categories` LIKE ?) and (`categories` LIKE ? or `categories` LIKE ? or `categories` LIKE ?) and (`categories` LIKE ?))
```